# Output JSON views_field_view with Services?

Tags: views, services

I am using Services Views to render JSON for a view that has a views_field_view. The JSON output from Services for the views_field_view field is currently a rendered HTML view. How can I make views_field_view render a JSON version of the output to be included with the parent view's JSON output?

UPDATE:

The content in the sub-view has a Geofield, which is causing problems in a Services display.
The view is set as an unformatted list. A Page display looks like this:

```
node_title: Marquette
Geofield: 44.977297200000, -93.270110200000
```

Then if I create a Services display with the same view (same fields), the output looks like this:

```
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'node_title' => 'Marquette',
     'nid' => '1335',
  ))
```

In a Services display, anything I try to do with a Geofield just outputs the nid.

Comment: I think you'd need to create a services display for the child view, then when it's rendered it should contain json

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with custom fields in Services Views that has been fixed in the latest dev version.

https://drupal.org/node/1647270